# How to heat my workshop?

Tags: heating

I want something that can warm it up fairly quickly. I may only be out there an hour or 2, but when I decide to work on a project I don't want to wait an hour or 2 for it to heat up. Right now I have a cheap portable oil heater and it takes a long time. Would prefer something cheap if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look into the [Mr Heater](http://www.mrheater.com/) brand of propane heaters. They make a round one that attaches on top of a standard propane tank like your bbq grill probably uses.

[image]

They make a full range of heaters up to giant ones that contractors use, but I'm only familiar with the round tank mounted ones.

I've been in house boats that use the single round burner mounted on a propane tank setup and they get unbearably hot after running the heater for a few minutes every so often.

Comment: I have a Portable Buddy heater from Mr Heater - can use in shop, my motorhome or even indoors (in a pinch) if the power is out.  Super handy and puts out an amazing amount of heat.  We will even use the larger tank top version to heat our grillin/beer drinking area while my buddies and I take a break from skiing - excellent products.

Comment: Specifically their radiant propane heaters if you want to warm up quickly -- radiant heaters provide instant heat because they're heating *objects* in the room (like you) and not trying to heat all the air.

Comment: @Tester101 what is the point of adding copyrighted photos to old responses that have already been answered?

Comment: Aren't these rated only for outdoor use?

Comment: @Zach: I'm pretty sure Tester101 is just improving the content of your already excellent answer by including a visual. I found it helpful, since I had never seen this product before, and it definitely caught my eye more than plain text would have done. I also don't think a company that holds a copyright on their product photo is going to mind the free advertising.

Comment: Cool, I just wasn't sure if it was 'kosher' to add images from the web.  I know that wouldn't fly over at wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

I like my [ceramic space heater](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?keyword=ceramic+space+heater&langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053); it warms up the otherwise unheated spot in my basement quickly.  If you choose one, make sure it has an automatic shutoff when tipped over, or for over-temperature conditions.  They start out pretty cheap at around $20; more money gets you nicer styling or features like a remote control.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an shop heater that works really quickly, look into a torpedo (aka Salamander) type heater.  They are a forced air heater so it will quickly warm any space you use it in.
They're commonly used on construction sites, I've been on many jobs in the dead of winter where the heat isn't running yet but a salamander heater is keeping a large uninsulated inside space warm when it's 20F outside.